# Display data from single database row in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a database table containing several entries, see below. These rows are first displayed in a list view using a SimpleCursorAdapter, the values displayed are the competing teams. When an item is selected I want to display all information in that row as a detailed showing all information, how do I do this?

**Edit** : The problem is not how to start the activity etc. It was just a background description to give an understanding of what I want to do. The problem is how to display a row from database in a list view!

Picture of database table:

[image: Database table]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto

Comment: That was not the problem, see edit.

Comment: Please google you will find a lots and lots of tutorial explaining what you are looking for.

Comment: I haven't  found a single one. There are a lot of tutorials describing how to use a cursor to get values from a database and displaying these as one item per row in a list view. But now I want to have one row for each column. You are free to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it..
[Display a single row in a listview (one listview-entry for every column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065011/display-a-single-row-in-a-listview-one-listview-entry-for-every-column)
Also be helpful this..
http://appfulcrum.com/2011/09/21/listview-example-5-using-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 0):

ok, the screen size of the Android phones in very less compared to the desktop/laptop screen size. Samsung Galaxy S III is around 4.8 inch whereas a laptop is around 13 inch. Therefor the UI/UX for phones have to thought off differently and therefore you did not find even a single implementation of what you are looking. You will have to rethink your UI. There are some wonderful blogs on UI/UX for Android/Mobile phone. Google.